# What is the best solution to have multiple copies of same website tailored to different cities?

Tags: google, duplicate-content, google-places

I'm a Canadian living in Thailand but I travel a lot to many countries, and I can freelance everywhere.

So I want multiple local versions of the same site, without getting hit with duplicate content by Google.

These sites will only be "Pay Per Clicked", no SEO except perhaps a single page per URL to get a Google places page.

Is there a way to COMPLETELY make other versions of the site INVISIBLE to Google?

Like the other sites don't even exist? The content I mean.

The sites will be identical to original site except for the text being targeted locally.

Comment: Doesn't Google just not take that into account if you use a valid way of setting up a multilingual site?

Comment: Sites will be in the same language, English, duplicate sites, but for different audiences, targeted locally

Comment: This question has been asked several times here one way or another. You can use noindex on the pages you do not want indexed. You can also possibly use the canonical tag. Here is what Google says about that: https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/139066?hl=en

Comment: @WilliamD.Edwards It has been a while - good to see you!!

Comment: @closetnoc thank you so much :-) How are you doing?!

Comment: @WilliamD.Edwards I am doing okay. Busy with major life issues that are beating me down for a while. **All normal stuff that anyone goes through.** A sick Mom, my dying cat (who I love), and a bad tenant. All I have to remember is that *I am going through* and these things do not last. It is just a period that lasts a season. I will come through okay as anyone does. How are you doing?? Cheers!!

Comment: @WilliamD.Edwards “Life is difficult. This is a great truth, one of the greatest truths. It is a great truth because once we truly see this truth, we transcend it. Once we truly know that life is difficult-once we truly understand and accept it-then life is no longer difficult. Because once it is accepted, the fact that life is difficult no longer matters.” - M. Scott Peck, The Road Less Traveled

Comment: @closetnoc Ouch. Best of luck with that!!! You're right, luckily they don't last and things will be better later :-) Personally I am very busy with school and my 'startup' which is still in its infancy) and I am developing a web app (which I could really use some help with) for a project which will be used on a couple of big festivals here in The Netherlands :-)

Comment: @WilliamD.Edwards Good luck with your coding! I'd chuck in, however, I promise you, I am so distracted that I would be God awful! I basically stopped coding back last summer and will pick it up again later this year. New site - new everything. Starting over.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on what you are stating, and the fact in comments you say that all the duplicate sites will be in English but targeting different audiences you have two options here...

Your first option is if the substantive content of the site will be the same across all the sites. If that is the case then your only real course of action would be to pick one site as the primary authoritative one and then define canonical meta tags on the corresponding pages of all the other sites linking to the corresponding pages on the main site.

The second option is if the substantive content of the site will be different across the sites. If that is the case then there is no issue with having the sites as if they where just several different sites as they would all have unique content.

There is a third option though and that would be not to have different sites for each country, especially if the languages will all be the same. What you could do in this instance is have one site with all of the substantive content on it, and then have one page per geographic area you service. This page would be area specific information, and the page that gets linked to from Google Places and Google+